# Reading a Serial Port with Python. How does the buffers work?

Tags: python, serial-port, buffer

I am just wondering how the buffers work on a com port.. The code below is a snip of how I am reading a com port. I am wondering if by doing `serial_connection.close()` and `serial_connection.open()` I would be losing any data, or would it remain in the buffer? You might ask why I am closing and opening the comport.. The reason being is that it is actually a virtual port and for what ever reason when I stay connected to it for a length of time data stops transmitting...

```
import serial

serial_connection = serial.Serial(
        port = self.SERIAL_PORT,
        baudrate = self.BAUD_RATE,
        timeout = 10
        )

while true:

    serial_connection.close()
    serial_connection.open()
    line = serial_connection.readline()
    print line
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PySerial has a separate thread that sits there listening for data to make sure that nothing gets lost. However, the OS itself does not buffer data. There is a slim chance that you could lose some data for the brief period of time between when you close the port and open it again.